# Taking derivative of integral containing an integral

Tags: calculus

Given this expression:

$$\int^{T}_{0} c(t)L(t)exp(\int^T_tr(s)ds)dt$$

how do I take derivative wrt to $T$?

I know that I should be using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and Chain Rule, but I'm not sure how to apply it.

My attempt:

$$F(T) = \int^{T}_{0} c(t)L(t)exp(\int^T_tr(s)ds)dt$$
Then:

$$F'(T) = c(t)L(t)exp(\int^T_tr(s)ds)r(T)$$

Comment: Noe that $F$ is just a function  of $T$, the symbol $t$ is a dummy variable. Your expression for $F'(T)$ is a function of $T$ and $t$ so you must realise it is not correct. Better try again? [Books on this topic show how to differentiate $\int_{0}^{x}f(x,t) dt$.]